# How to handle an electronic device with a mixed model?

Tags: r, mixed-model

I have lots of photo diodes of the same type and I want to investigate them with the help of a mixed model with R (I just made my first steps via some tutorials). First of all I would like to know how I start respectively how I specify the model. For each photo diode I have about ten measurement data points (current/amplification against voltage) before and after an irradiation. And these data points vary from device to device (before and also after irradiation). Above all I need a certain amplification/current of the corresponding voltage. There is a standard fit in the literature but it is not as good as I need it, meaning its error is way too high. So how do I gain the demanded voltage, how do I start? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: "I want to investigate them" What is your actually research question? You need to develop some kind of hypothesis or at least a specific question before you start considering models.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your answer! The goal is the following: I have several measurement data points but I need a corresponding value to a data point which has not been measured.
I asked a mathematician what to do and he said I've to use mixed models. Then I tried go get into the stuff and because of my understanding, a mixed model will give me nice errors of the measurements (?) but not a corresponding value (?) so I asked someone else. And he said independently the same that I have to use mixed models.
Sure I can ask them asgain but I feel a little bit dumb at the moment..

Comment: "I have several measurement data points but I need a corresponding value to a data point which has not been measured" A statistician would say you want to predict. However, it it unclear what kind of explanatory data you have available and whether you have some kind of time series and perhaps want to forecast. With the meager information you provide it is impossible to give sound advice.

Comment: Whether to use mixed models or not is a secondary issue. First you need to decide if you should use a non-linear model (based on the science behind this), a linear model, or a non-parametric model. Possibly some approaches from machine learning might be useful. Or you need a time series model.

Comment: @Roland Thanks again! Yes, to predict sounds properly. 
The measurements are not given by time. Sure, they are but the labaratory does not share this information with us. All we have are about ten corresponding current<>voltage data points for each device (before and after an irradiation). And each device behaves differently. Here is a sketch: https://www.file-upload.net/download-12540258/Selection_183.png.html 
https://www.file-upload.net/download-12540257/Selection_182.png.html

I know that linear or nonlinear depends not on the curve itself (which is nonlinear) but how do I learn this?

Comment: You want to predict M in dependence of U/V? The curve looks like a simple quadratic model might be appropriate, but ultimately this depends on the science behind this curve, which you should know something about. Please add all relevant information and graphs to the question. I don't understand the *Selection_182* graph. It that a histogram? Then you might want to use a bimodal distribution model.

Comment: THanks again! No, but vice versa! I need the corresponding voltage to a certain M (for all devices). M is an amplification (of the current). There is a standard formula/fit in the literature but it is not as good as we need it. The error of it is way too high.
Sorry! Selection_182 shows the distribution/histogram of all devices. There I used this standard fit to get the demanded voltage because for a feeling of the distribution it is sufficient. But not for a single device to operate it.

Comment: Please add this information to the question by editing it. I would fit the formula from the literature, a GAM (provided you have a sufficient number of data points) and a quadratic function. All of these can be fit as a mixed model. Then I would compare performance of these models, e.g., by using cross validation.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! So I fit the data points separately with the standard fit, a GAM and a quadratic function. Then I compare them with a mixed model to get to know which is better?

Comment: No, each of the fits should be a mixed model and you should compare their predictive performance.

Comment: Sorry, isn't that the same? Probably I didn't express properly. I do the following:
Fit data points with quadratic fit -> Mixed Model -> obtain p-value. Then fit data points with standard fit -> Mixed Model -> obtain p-value. Then fit data points with GAM -> Mixed Model -> obtain p-value. 
At the end I compare the p-values and the one with the highest is the best fit.

Comment: No, you fit a quadratic LMM, a NLMM and a GAMM and crossvalidate all of them. p-values are not of interest since you are interested in predictive performance.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for my constant asking again: What will the models reveal? Can I extract the demanded voltage from them? Do I get a new fit?

Comment: I'm sorry but you appear to need more help than can be given in a quick internet post. You should hire a consultant.

Comment: Can you maybe provide me some sources or books so I can (easily) get better into the topics? As you probably already know it's a little bit hard for me to separate and estimate all the various things. I also read really a lot but I still don't know when and why to use something.

Comment: Maybe for someone else this can be useful: http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-tutorial-4/